# Passing an array to the function in C++ and finding size

Tags: c++, arrays

I am confused with how array is passed to the function. In this code..

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void func(int arr[])
{
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << n << endl;
}

int main()
{
    int arr[] = {3,6,2,4,7,9,5,1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    cout << n << endl;
    func(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The output I am getting is

8

1

Can someone please explain why this is so?

Comment: _"I am confused with how array is passed to the function."_ I'm not surprised! **It's not.**

Answer (score 0):

When an array is passed to a function it automatically decays to a pointer. Although you write `int arr[]` as an argument, `arr` is a pointer and `sizeof(arr)` yields `sizeof(T*)`. Dereferencing a `int*` yields `int`. On your machine `int*` and `int` happen to have the same size, so `sizeof(int*) / sizeof(int) == 1`.